# how to add label on search result?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add a label on a search result?
please check the picture for reference 
I just want to separate the two results
with the specific title how can I achieve that?

[here's the result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfDeB.png)

[For your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kfdt.png)

```html
<script>
  /* globals global */
  jQuery(function($) {
    var searchRequest;
    $('.search-autocomplete').autoComplete({
      minChars: 2,
      source: function(term, suggest) {
        try {
          searchRequest.abort();
        } catch (e) {}
        searchRequest = $.getJSON(global.ajax, {
          q: term,
          action: 'search_site'
        }, function(res) {
          //console.log(res.data);
          var suggestions = [];
          res.data.forEach(x => {
            console.log(x);
            if (~x.post_title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) {
              suggestions.push(x.post_title);
            } else if (~x.post_status.toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) {
              suggestions.push(x.post_title);
            }
            suggest(suggestions);
          });
          //  for (i=0;i<res.data.length;i++)
          //       if (~res.data.post_title[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(res.data.post_title[i]);
          //  suggest(suggestions);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://localhost/gigant-live/">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="s" class="form-control search-autocomplete" id="s" placeholder="My Search form" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry not entirely understanding what you're asking. Can you give a specific example with the picture you shared?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato sorry for that please check my "here's the result of my code" I edit my post

Comment: So if I'm not wrong, you want it so there are 3 "rows" of the search result: one as a general label saying "Accounting", and two under saying "Manager 2" and "Manager"?

Comment: What I want is to copy the layout "For your reference" I just want to add Title for example Category (result will show) Tags (result will show)

Comment: so therefore conclude I want to show the category and Tags on my search result

Comment: Okay can you explain how you would like the `here's the result of my code` picture to look? Because I'm not seeing how it related to the reference picture..

Comment: I want to have a title base on the result of my search like to the picture(reference picture)

Comment: For your reference image has a users and services title I want that to achieve on my own search result

Comment: I suggest you remove your two snippits and add a working code snippit that includes the JS and HTML code that is working that will return the result your picture shows. This will allow others to copy the snippit to their answer and will likely give you a working answer much quicker ;)

Comment: @dalelandry I merged it but It's not working

Comment: you need to enable jquery in your sippit

Comment: @dalelandry It's not working sir

Comment: maybe because I'm using this wp_localize_script(
        'global',
        'global',
        array(
            'ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.[jquery/auto-complete](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)

```js
$(".search-autocomplete").autoComplete({
        minChars: 1,
        source: function (term, suggest) {
          term = term.toLowerCase();
          var choices = [
            { label: "a", value: "apple" },
            { label: "b", value: "boy" },
            { label: "c", value: "car" },
          ];
          var suggestions = [];
          for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)
            if (choices[i].value.indexOf(term) !== -1) {
              suggestions.push(choices[i]);
            }
          suggest(suggestions);
        },
        renderItem: function (item, search) {
          return (
            '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion">' +
            '<span style="color: red; margin-right: 10px">' +
            item.label +
            "</span>" +
            "<span>" +
            item.value +
            "</span>" +
            "</div>"
          );
        },
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input
      type="text"
      autocomplete="off"
      value=""
      name="s"
      class="search-autocomplete"
      id="s"
      placeholder="My Search form"
    />
```

Comment: I'm not good in javascript how can I insert that code to my script?

Comment: like this.$('.search-autocomplete').autoComplete({
      minChars: 2,
      source: function(term, suggest) {...},_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
  return ***
}

Comment: my autocomplete is working I just want to add some label text for result

Comment: wait me for a while

Comment: Without considering the ajax request, I did a simple demo

Comment: where is it sir?

Comment: my answer above

Comment: Sir, can I request a remote to you to access my computer?

Comment: I can't sir my script won't work when I try to apply it

Comment: Try again. I changed the dependency

Comment: I'm confuse here { label: "a", value: "apple" },
            { label: "b", value: "boy" },
            { label: "c", value: "car" }, because i have my own value I don't know how can I apply yours

Comment: confused...I just want to see a real response of your ajax request.Otherwise I suggest you read my code several times

Comment: "choices" in my core Represents the core data to be request by your ajax request, good luck sir

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDVHXVFNHD08

You need to make unique set of labels or you can loop through the result sets and append the label only once

```
var headers = [];

if(!headers.includes(section[i])){   //section will contains the lables         
    label = document.createElement("H2"); 
    label.innerHTML = section[i];
    headers.push(section[i]);            
    resultSet.appendChild(label);
}
```

Comment: can you apply that to my script tag? Im not good in javascript sir @Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

```
    function ja_ajax_search() {
    $results = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     => array( 'product','product-tag' ,'post_author'),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'nopaging'      => true,
        'posts_per_page'=> 100,
        's'             => stripslashes( $_POST['search'] ),
    ) );

    $items = array();


    // print_r($results);
    if ( !empty( $results->posts ) ) {

        foreach ( $results->posts as $result) {
            // $services = [$result ];
            $post_details = [
                'post_id' => $result->ID,
                'post_author' => $result->post_author,
                'post_title' => $result->post_title,
                'post_status' => $result->post_status,
                'post_slug' => $result->post_name
            ];
            array_push($items, $post_details);
            // $items[] .= $services;
            // echo $result->post_title;

        }


    }
    // print_r($items);
    // print_r($items);
    // print_r($items);

    // if ( !empty( $results->posts ) ) {

    //     foreach ( $results->posts as $result ) {
    //         $items[] = $result->post_status;
    //     }
    // }




    wp_send_json_success( $items ); 

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_site',        'ja_ajax_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_site', 'ja_ajax_search' );
```